# Where does Log4Net store it's logs?

Tags: log4net

I have a WinForms application and I'm currently evaluating Log4Net.

When I close the application and delete the log file, I expect to lose the logs. What happens is I launch the application and the logs of the last session get written in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4net does not store the logs in a specific place. You can configure log4net where to store the logs. The basic principle is that you configure log appenders in configuration. This way you are flexible in where you are logging. There are many possible appenders, for example:

- file
- sql
- eventlog
- debug
- blob storage
- ...

for a overview of 'out of the box' appenders: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.html

Each appender has different configuration options. You can have multiple appenders to log to different 'endpoints'.